# SSIS package fails when deployed to the SSIS Catalog with “The expression cannot be evaluated. Modify the expression to be valid”

Tags: sql-server, ssis, upsert, catalog

I have written an SSIS package that is intended to handle our daily upserts. Extract .csv files are deposited from a central clinical application in the early hours of the morning on to a VM. The SSIS package in question (DailyUpdate.dtsx) is designed to keep our local instance up to date. Everything works fine in Visual Studio (which is installed on the VM), however when deployed the package refuses to run (on the server housing SQL Server).
The package uses two parameters at the project level.

| Name: | Type: | Value: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| InputFilePath4Extracts | String | C:\SRextracts\ |
| ServerName | String | WH-TEAM-DEV |

If I am thinking about this correctly, I can kind of understand why InputFilePath4Extracts would fail. The .csv files in question are obviously not on the C drive of the server housing SQL server, they are on the C: drive of the VM, could that be the reason? Why the ServerName would fail is more confusing to me as that obviously is local to that server. Of course, I could be entirely wrong in my thinking. Historically, when I have written any SSIS packages everything has been on the one server.

> "DailyUpdate:Error: The expression "@[$Project::ServerName]" on property >\Package.Connections[WH-TEAM->ServerName.ClinicalSyS].Properties[ServerName]" cannot be evaluated. Modify >the expression to be valid.

> "DailyUpdate:Error: Attempt to parse the expression >"@[$Project::InputFilePath4Extracts] + "SRPatientRegistration.csv"" failed >and returned error code 0xC00470A6. The expression cannot be parsed. It >might contain invalid elements, or it might not be well-formed. There may >also be an out-of-memory error."

Any suggestions appreciated.